# Assign VNC password using script

Tags: bash, password, vnc, scripts, tightvncserver

I am using a script to automatically set up a computer. I need to assign a password to the vnc server for the user, which is normally done using the `vncserver` command. However, it prompts for the user to enter and re-enter their password, neither of which the script is capable of doing. So, how can I set up the VNC password without an interactive prompt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, the vncserver command only prompts for a password if the password file (by default, $HOME/.vnc/passwd) is absent - typically the first time it's run for a particular user. You could either script that initial vncserver interaction using 'expect', or pre-create the user's password file by calling the vncpasswd utility via expect *before* you run vncserver for the first time; e.g. [CAUTION: this is absolutely minimal, you should add some sanity checks if this is used in a serious environment]

```
#!/bin/sh

prog=/usr/bin/vncpasswd
mypass="newpass"

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn "$prog"
expect "Password:"
send "$mypass\r"
expect "Verify:"
send "$mypass\r"
expect eof
exit
EOF
```

If you don't want to (or can't) use 'expect', then there are various hacks available on the web - VNC passwords apparently use a form of DES encryption so searching with the terms 'VNC' 'DES' 'password' should get you what you need (I'm not going to link here since I cannot vouch for any particular one).

For completeness, note that the default Ubuntu 'Desktop Sharing' uses vino, and the password for *that* appears to be simply base64 encoded, so it is possible to set it directly e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password "$(echo -n "newpass" | base64)"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 12):

Was able to do it this way today (from a dockerfile at least):

```
RUN printf "password\npassword\n\n" | vncpasswd
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest cleanest way. Works in a script and in my case I'm using `su` and it works there as well, i.e.
`su -l -c 'printf "password\npassword\n\n" | vncpasswd' username`

Comment: Using the above comment by @raj worked well for me (I'm on VNC4): `sudo printf "password\npassword\n\n" | vnc4passwd`

Answer (score 12):

I found another way of doing this in a script (as root):

```
#!/bin/sh    

myuser="asimov"
mypasswd="mysecret"

mkdir /home/$myuser/.vnc
echo $mypasswd | vncpasswd -f > /home/$myuser/.vnc/passwd
chown -R $myuser:$myuser /home/$myuser/.vnc
chmod 0600 /home/$myuser/.vnc/passwd
```

Cheers!

Comment: Did you launch vncserver any differently after doing this?  When I set the passwd file manually, I'm still prompted to specify a password when I run vncserver.

Comment: best answer IMOH

Comment: To clarify for others what this is doing, -f prints to STDOUT and then redirects the output to the passwd file with the >.

Answer (score 2):

By slightly modifying [steeldriver's version](https://askubuntu.com/a/328323/618497) I was able to automate my usage of vncpasswd. Allows passing both the password and filename for vncpasswd to create.

Usage: `$ ./scriptname <filename> <password>`

```
#!/bin/sh    

myuser="$1"
mypass="$2"

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn /usr/bin/vncpasswd $myuser
expect "Password:"
send "$mypass\r"
expect "Verify:"
send "$mypass\r"
expect eof
exit
EOF
```

Comment: It's generally discouraged to pass secrets as command-line arguments because they can be viewed by all users.

Answer (score 0):

In Ansible (requires `pexpect` to be installed on target):

```yaml
    - name: Set vnc password for tigervnc
      expect:
        command: vncpasswd /home/{{ UserName }}/.vnc/passwd
        responses:
          (?i)password: "max8char"
          (?i)verify: "max8char"
          (?i)\(y/n\): "n"
```