# How to run a program and pass parameters through a shell scribt in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, scripts, gnome-terminal, tightvncserver

I want to run vncserver in terminal, to automate it with several other commands I've put it inside a shell script. However, when you call vncserver for the first time, it asks you to set a password.

I tried:

```
vncserver -mychosenpass
```

but this doesn't work and it's still asking me to set a password like i hadn't set a parameter at all. I know that running vncserver, will raise 3 prompts, the first to ask what password to set, the second will ask me to retype that password to confirm and the last prompt i want to reply with "n". How can i automate this through my shell script?

Comment: In the general case, you can script interactive sessions using the `expect` program. For this particular case however, see [Assign VNC password using script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328240/assign-vnc-password-using-script)